# Upgrading Solr from 6.0.0 to 8.7.0

Tags: solr, upgrade

I have a Solr v6.0.0 running in a single server setup with only one core on windows environment and the core has a defined schema. I see see instructions for upgrading a Solr cluster (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/upgrading-a-solr-cluster.html) but not single server setup. I tried to figure out if I can get an idea on what need to be done for single server setup based on it but it talks about installing Solr as a Service for Linux environment but doesn't talk anything about windows. I also looked at the IndexUpgraderTool, but it only upgrades index data files. Since the core has defined schema, how do I upgrade it? Can I drop the whole core folder in the new solr version folder(after upgrading the index)? This is the first time I am upgrading the Solr, I feel lost.

Comment: If you're already using the `*Point` types, your configuration should be backwards compatible and Solr should be able to read the indexes out of the box (iirc there's two versions of backwards compatibility in Lucene; otherwise you'll have to go via a 7.x.x version). You can test this by making a copy of your index + configuration directory to your local machine, then running Solr-8.x with that directory directly. In single server setups (if you're just using cores), everything for a core is located inside the cores directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately my configuration uses Trie* fields. So, what is the best approach to update the schema.xml file?

Comment: TrieFields should still work fine, but as they're deprecated they may not in the future. However, for 8.x they're still present.